# Unmarshaling JSON using Jackson returning null in Android

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, marshalling

I have the following code:

```
 FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput(userFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mapper.writeValue(fileOutputStream, user);
        String userStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
        fileOutputStream.close();
```

Since userStr displays the correct JSON string i am assuming the marshalling works. 
When I try to do this afterwards :

```
  FileInputStream fileInputStream = context.openFileInput(userFileName);
            user = mapper.readValue(fileInputStream, User.class);
            fileInputStream.close();
```

user's fields are all null. I cannot understand what is happening. I tried to verify if file exists and it does. Here is my User class:

```
public class User {

    private static User instance;

    private String fullName;
    private URL photoURL;
    private String phone;
    private String address;

    private User() {
        // private no-arg constructor since this is a singleton class
    }


    public static User getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new User();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return instance.fullName + photoURL.toString() + phone + address;
    }


    // Getters
    public String getFullName() {
        return instance.fullName;
    }

    public URL getPhotoURL() {
        return instance.photoURL;
    }

    public String getPhone(){
        return instance.phone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return instance.address;
    }

    // Setters
    public void setFullName (String fullName) {
        instance.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public void setPhotoURL (URL photoURL) {
        instance.photoURL = photoURL;
    }

    public void setPhone (String phone) {
        instance.phone = phone;
    }

    public void setAddress (String address) {
        instance.address = address;
    }
}
```

This is the user.json content

```
{"address":"Babbrruu","fullName":"Test User","phone":"+3556060231","photoURL":"http://www.ipizza.al/testuser.jpg"}
```

Comment: post the json and the mapper. also check the actual content of the file.

Comment: I dont know how to read the file.

Comment: {"address":"Babbrruu","fullName":"Test User","phone":"+3556060231","photoURL":"http://www.ipizza.al/testuser.jpg"} this is the content of the file